# Dell Inspiron 1300 hangup during boot

Tags: boot, dell, inspiron

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on this machine.  It has 256MB RAM. I have created a bootable CD but when booting, it stalls on the Ubuntu screen with 5 red spots. Is this the wrong version for this machine? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Resolve that problem by hitting <kbd>F6</kbd> and typing in `b43.blacklist=yes` before selecting to install.